# WITH - WHERE in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Can anyone explain the difference between 2 queries: (I changed the order WHERE and WITH)

```
MATCH (t:Transaction)
WHERE t.AcctNumber = '001'
WITH COLLECT(t.ActivityDate) as date, COLLECT(t.Amount) as amount, t
RETURN t.AccNumber, date, amount
```

and

```
MATCH (t:Transaction)
WITH COLLECT(t.ActivityDate) as date, COLLECT(t.Amount) as amount, t
WHERE t.AcctNumber = '001'
RETURN t.AccNumber, date, amount
```

Does the order of WHERE and WITH have effect on the performance of my query?
#Neo4j, cypher

Comment: You should be aware that your aggregation is incorrect and you will get wrong results from this. This is because `t` is a grouping key in your aggregation, so your collect()s are being performed per `t` node. In other words, each row will contain the t node, a single-element list of its own activity date, and a single-element list of its own amount. You would get the same results (minus the lists around each) by doing `RETURN t.AccNumber, t.ActivityDate as date, t.Amount as amount`. If you want to collect over more than just each single node, remove `t` from your grouping key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'PROFILE [your query]' to see what happens. Without a testable data set I can't show you, but in the first query you collect info on a selection (t.acctNumber = 001), whereas in the second query you collect all transactions and on all transactions you filter. So in short, the first query you minimize the number of hits to work on straightaway, whereas in the second you only do that after collection and that requires more computational power.

Comment: Agree, but if I used the second query, is there any alternative way to improve the performance like using index?

Comment: @DacHo You need the WHERE to follow the MATCH for there to be leveraging of an index, provided you've created one, and provided you've included the label and indexed property.

Answer (score 0):

> Where in Match clause will filter the result of the match thus it will
> return fewer records.  For with and where clause, it will filter the
> result of the rows that you are collecting. Thus, the first query has
> more performance gain.

I will use your first query.